# Passing in Value other than recordId into Screen Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I included a visual screen flow into our page layout. It gives me the option to "pass the record ID into this variable." and when I select it fills the variable with {!Record.Id}

Then I started thinking... I have a variable Stage, can I pass it the variable {!Record.StageName}? Basically I am asking if {!Record. Anything } will pass any field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is available via [URL parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_url_set_variable.htm)

Otherwise you can simply execute the GetRecord Action with the record ID and thereby "query" any field value you need.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you create an input variable of Data Type 'Record' in your Flow  - name it 'record' and when you add the Screen Flow to the record page in Lightning App Builder you check the box that says 'Pass all field values from the record into this flow variable'.

Then in your flow, you have access to all the fields from that record variable.  No need to query.